# Unable to see images, css files or use javascript in MVC 3 website deployed on IIS 7 in classic mode

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, deployment, iis-7

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 website that works perfectly in IIS7 integrated mode. However, I need to deploy this in classic mode.

In order to do so, we manually inserted the handler mappings in IIS to handle urls for .mvc extensions as suggested in the link in the global.asax file.

But in classic mode, none of the static files (css, images, javascript) are getting loaded. Is there some other setting that I need to do to get these working.

When I tried to see these in fiddler, I can see an HTTP error 500 for all of them. I have already tried the following approaches:

- Added the following line of code in the web.config httpHandlers section

  add verb="*" path="*.png" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler"
- Checked the 'Static Content' in Common HTTP features on IIS.

I am not sure what to try next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to improper relative paths, which didn't work out when we deployed. Having the proper relative path showed the images and other files perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The usual workaround is to configure "Wildcard Script Map", please read more [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/deployment/using-asp-net-mvc-with-different-versions-of-iis-cs).